# Is Nescibat valid for Nesciēbat?

Tags: spelling, syncopated-perfect

Encountered the word *nescibat* in a text where other version of the same text reads *nesci**e**bat*. I'm not sure if *nescibat* is a valid spelling variant [there are legitimate different spellings between those versions like *nego**c**ium* and *nego**t**ium*] or simply a typo.

[I saw](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=%20nescibam&la=la) that for the first person *nescibam* is valid for *nesci**e**bam*, but could not verify for the 3rd person.

Comment: Where did you see that the first person version is valid? I don't see why the same wouldn't hold for all persons.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, I've edited the post with link to Perseus: "verb 1st sg imperf ind act poetic", but they don't accept this poetic(?) structure for the 3rd person. But without the -ne, they [do](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=%20scibat&la=la). So it is due to nescibat not being attested.

Comment: I think that is reading too much into attestations as I alluded to in my answer. Given the attestations around that specific form, I don't have any proper grounds to reject it just because of lack of attestation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A corpus search shows [18 hits for *scibam*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=scibam%23) including four with *ne-* and [4 hits for *scibat*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=scibat%23) with none with *ne-*.
The variants [*sciebam*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=sciebam%23) and [*sciebat*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=sciebat%23) have 79 and 145 hits (15 and 22 with *ne-*), respectively.

Overall, it seems that the imperfect endings without the *-e-* are rare.
For example, I found [only one occurrence of *audibat*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=audibat%23) but [36 for *audiebat*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=audiebat%23).

Based on this, I would say that *nescibat* is a valid variant but just happens not to be attested.
Dropping the *-e-* is possible but so rare that it does not occur for all words in all forms in the attested literature.
I expect different authors to have different spelling preferences, but I have not looked into this aspect further, as it is beyond the scope of your question.
And it is certainly possible that different editors have their own preferences too, but based on the numbers I found, I see no reason to argue *nescibat* to be invalid.
I think declaring *nescibat* invalid is reading too much into the attestations.

However, it should be noted — as C. M. Weimer pointed out in a comment — that most if not all of the attestations appear to be from poetry.
Therefore the transformation *sciebat > scibat* may be taken as metric flexibility rather than a feature of normal speech.
But being as common as the phenomenon is, I find it hard to believe that it would sound very alien to a Roman ear.
A more careful formulation of the answer is that *nescibat* is certainly valid in poetry, but its status is less clear in prose.

Comment: You missed something major in your examples: every single attestation you found comes from poetry.

Comment: @cmw Excellent point! I added a paragraph on that.